# Faster Bulk XML nodes update

Tags: xml, xquery

We are using XML database and storing XML values in XML data type columns. for example for Organisation and Employees the XML will be as given below.

```xml
<Organisation>
    <OrganisationNumber>1001</OrganisationNumber>
    <Employees>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
            <EmployeeNumber>ABC1</EmployeeNumber>
            <EmployeeName>EmployeeName1</EmployeeName>
            <EmployeeType>Type1</EmployeeType>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
            <EmployeeNumber>XYZ2</EmployeeNumber>
            <EmployeeName>EmployeeName2</EmployeeName>
            <EmployeeType>Type1</EmployeeType>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
</Organisation>
```

1 Organisation may contain around 1500 Employees so the XML for 1 Organisation is of very large size.

Problem arises when we have to update any node value for all 1500 Employees. As 'Modify(Replace Value Of)' updates only 1 node at once we have to apply loop for updating all nodes. This takes quite a long time. We tried creating Primary and secondary XML indexes but that doesn't improve update speed.

Is there any other way to do bulk update than using Replace value Of in XQuery?

Comment: Please also describe what XML database system you're using, and how you're doing the loop. Looking at your data, a RDBMS might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

So the words "XML data type columns" in the question reliably tell me that you are not in fact using a Native XML database, but are rather using an RDBMS with XML Column support.

You can do this in XQuery Update, but I suspect the problem you are experiencing is not XQuery related, rather it is the performance of placing XML documents into an RDBMS (in my experience very bad).

The following XQuery is an example of updating all EmployeeTypes with a single expression -

replace value of node //EmployeeType with "TypeZ"

You may find it is quicker to extract the document from the RDBMS, process it and then ovewrite the original document in the RDBMS. My advice would be to use a Native XML Database instead for XML documents (e.g. eXist, BaseX, MarkLogic etc).